# Face recognition - Local Binary Pattern Histogram comparison

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, histogram, face-recognition

I have two images, i convert them to gray scale and find out the Local Binary Pattern for both of them. How can i compare the histograms to see if they match?. What is the formula? (also what is Chi-Square? - came across it when researching)

Comment: Are you looking for face detection or face recognitions? Detection means finding any face in a picture, recognition means finding a specific persone (e.g Your grandma) in a face picture.

Comment: hi, i am looking to perform face recognition using local binary pattern histogram.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Chi-Square: The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) is very good and very thorough.

You would use a "[chi-squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) for goodness of fit" to compare distributions. Histograms are "color distributions" so this test is applicable to your problem.

The one you want to use for your two distributions is the [Pearson's chi-squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test).